# Example of eager loading in entity framwork 5.0

Tags: entity-framework-5

I am trying to implement **eager loading in entity framework**.
Could you please share the way, how to eager loading in entity framework ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search gives a great example of [eager loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx), but the premise is to basically include the foreign entities with the query:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
  .Include(x => x.Posts) // this is eager loading
  .ToList();
```

You just want to grab the foreign entities with the original entities using `.Include()`.

Note you can also disable lazy loading as a default within `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```